# Wordpress Single Post Pagination Numbered and Navigational

Tags: php, posts, pagination

I already have a Pagination on my Post [Single Post Pagination using `<!--nextpage-->` ] and it looks **something like this...**

[image: Default Single Post Pagination]

**Now, I want to change it to...**

[image: Required Pagination]

I have gone through few documentations and stuff on pages, it's related to wp_link_pages I think... But I can't seem to add this pagination and when ever i try, I break my theme. Honestly at the moment I haven't come up with any codes, I just use what I find on the Internet which implies I am not good with this kind of thing, Obviously I asked question on stackexchange to help me clear this issue. Thank you so much for any kind of help.

Comment: Can you add the current pagination code/template to your question?

Comment: @SallyCJ It is the default theme Pagination & it uses [wp_link_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) but the thing is, I did not make it, it is theme default.

Comment: Well then, you can use [`next_posts_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_posts_link/) and [`previous_posts_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_posts_link/). You will need to add it in the pagination template, or in your template, at an appropriate location/position.

Comment: @SallyCJ I think you are mistaken here... that is for posts Pagination, not "Single Post Pagination" as in Splitting a **Single Post** to **Multiple Pages**

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll see if I can come up with something else that you can try.

Comment: thank you, as long as u can help :D btw I think we can create an If-Else statement using Post ID/Permalink & Page Number of the Single Post... that is something like... `if` page < max_pages (then) post-permalink/$page+1 "Next Page" & post-permalink/$page-1 "Previous Page" ... `else` (page = max_pages)  post-permalink/$page-1 "Previous Page" ... Ok so this is the basic idea, am not good with php or wordpress but this is an approach, (also all these codes aren't real, this is just a reference)